# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable in spectogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, spectrogram

I am trying to do two spectrograms in Python with the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


sampling_frequency_48kHz = 48000
t_48kHz = np.linspace(0, 10, sampling_frequency_48kHz * 10)
signal_48kHz = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 5 * t_48kHz)

sampling_frequency_8kHz = 8000
t_8kHz = np.linspace(0, 10, sampling_frequency_8kHz * 10)
signal_8kHz = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 5 * t_8kHz)

window_size = 0.03 
overlap = 0 
nfft = 2048 

plt.figure()
plt.specgram(signal_48kHz, Fs=sampling_frequency_48kHz, window=window_size, noverlap=overlap, NFFT=nfft)
plt.title('Spektrogram pro 48 kHz')

nfft = 512 

plt.figure()
plt.specgram(signal_8kHz, Fs=sampling_frequency_8kHz, window=window_size, noverlap=overlap, NFFT=nfft)
plt.title('Spektrogram pro 8 kHz')

plt.show()
```

But it shows me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\OneDrive\Dokumenty\4_7.py", line 18, in <module>
    plt.specgram(signal_48kHz, Fs=sampling_frequency_48kHz, window=window_size, noverlap=overlap, NFFT=nfft)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2818, in specgram
    __ret = gca().specgram(
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1423, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 7709, in specgram
    spec, freqs, t = mlab.specgram(x=x, NFFT=NFFT, Fs=Fs,
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 780, in specgram
    spec, freqs, t = _spectral_helper(x=x, y=None, NFFT=NFFT, Fs=Fs,
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 377, in _spectral_helper
    window = window(np.ones(NFFT, x.dtype))
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Where is the mistake I can't find it. I checked all variables, but I didnt find where was the problem.

Comment: `window` param needs to be a callable or array: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.specgram.html

Answer (score 0):

You're not complying with the expected keywork arguments to `specgram()` on line 18:

```
plt.specgram(signal_48kHz, Fs=sampling_frequency_48kHz, window=window_size, noverlap=overlap, NFFT=nfft)
                              ^                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

On that line:

```
window=
```

expects a function or a vector of length NFFT. You're passing in a float, which is why you get that error.  According to the docs:

> windowcallable or ndarray, default: window_hanning
> A function or a vector of length NFFT.
> To create window vectors see window_hanning,
> window_none, numpy.blackman, numpy.hamming, numpy.bartlett,
> scipy.signal, scipy.signal.get_window, etc. If a function is passed as
> the argument, it must take a data segment as an argument and return
> the windowed version of the segment.

See https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.specgram.html for more details

As a side note, I tried changing:

```
window=window_size
```

to:

```
window=[window_size,]*nfft
```

to make that single float value into a list of floats, but the prog complains that some resultant numpy array is too big. I barely use numpy, so I can't help further.